# How to do project-wide find or search/replace in Intellij on Mac?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I am a veteran of Intellij Idea on Linux (and going back several years on Windows as well).  I used the Alt-S-F (project global find) and Alt-S-R (project global search/replace) frequently.

Where is that functionality on Mac?

Note: I am not referring to Command-F or Command-R -> they simply do find or replace in the current file.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I found it. The terminology is "Find in Path" (not "Find in Project").

Answer (score 5):

@javadba the terminology is "Replace in Path" or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

(I'd have responded to your comment, but I don't have the rep yet)

Comment: from my answer over 5 years ago: `The terminology is "Find in Path" (not "Find in Project").` . The `replace` is same way.

Answer (score 1):

It is `Command` + `Shift` + `F` for Mac.

You can restrict your search to a folder using the `Directory`option, and also to files ending with an extension using `File Mask`.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> is the shortcut for Mac.